# Can a Chrome extension's window change its icon programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I made an app for Chrome OS that launches a Crouton program in a window using xiwi. I would like to make the app automatically change the Crouton window's icon so I can know which app is what. I tried using `chrome.browserAction.setIcon` (which changes the icon in the toolbar) as well as adding an 'icon' entry to `chrome.windows.create` (which didn't work), but that still didn't work. I found that using `chrome.app.window.create` with the 'icon' entry works, but the Crouton extension is not an app. Is is possible to change the icon of a Chrome extension's window programmatically?

Comment: Try `chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener` and check

Comment: I was able to make the script add a favicon `link` element to change the icon at the top, though I still can't get the shelf icon to change.